# How to add text as prefix

Tags: android, pdf

I wanted to open a file without downloading it so i used `window.open` in InAppBrowser and it works fine in ios... But i am not able to open a `pdf` file this way on android. 
I was able to open a `pdf` file using google doc by prefixing like my url:

```
https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=<my_url>
```

Now its opening `pdf` files, but files with images (.png) or text (.txt) cannot be opened this way, because they will be shown as html files.

So, when i get a pdf file on an android device it should check if the last three characters are matching (pdf) and in that case add a prefix to open the pdf file. All other files should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
String url = "my_pdf.pdf";
if(url.endsWith(".pdf")){           
    url = "https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + url;
}
```

Comment: var ref = window.open('http://www.w3.org/2011/web-apps-ws/papers/Nitobi.pdf', '_blank', 'location=yes'); my code is like this so how i can